# className did not match when using nextjs and react-jss

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jss

I'm using nextjs with typescript and react-jss. I get the error:

```
Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "mobileNavToggle-0-2-10" Client: "mobileNavToggle-0-2-2"
```

I think this is caused because the SSR and hydration produce different class names. This only seems to happen when I reload the page manually, not when next automatically reloads the page. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem adding a `_document.js` like in the `with-react-jss` example:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/master/examples/with-react-jss/pages/_document.js

Comment: I am still facing this issue after implementing the _document.js changes in given link. Any other solutions on this?